# Is this the right way to have "global" parameters for my servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, config

If I have:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>SomeParam</param-name>
    <param-value>SomeValue</param-value>
  </context-param>
```

in my `web.xml`, is this the servlet way of specifying options ( like in the way a config file is used ) , or am I doing something wrong? I know about `init-param` that can be specified for a servlet, but I'd like o make sure some values are the same for all the servlets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<context-param>` is to define context-wide initialization parameters which is available to **all** servlets. Inside a servlet you can obtain them by [`ServletContext#getInitParameter()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29), e.g.

```
public void init() {
    String someParam = getServletContext().getInitParameter("someParam");
}
```

That's the right way to have a "global" parameter for all your servlets. But you can also define servlet-specific initialization parameters inside `<servlet>` as follows:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>someParam</param-name>
        <param-value>someValue</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
```

You can obtain them by the *inherited* [`GenericServlet#getInitParameter()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html#getInitParameter%28java.lang.String%29) method. E.g.

```
public void init() {
    String someParam = getInitParameter("someParam");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah you are right.Go ahead it works fine.